# Applying pagination on keen's extraction api

Tags: keen-io

I've large number of messages in a keen collection and want to expose them to our end users through pagination using an api. Is it possible to specify offset like queries in Keen ?

We earlier had tradition database so were able to support above operations and thinking to shift to Keen  because of it's easier analysis capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to paginate extractions.

We created the Extractions API to allow you to get your event data out of Keen IO any time you like. It's your data and we believe that you should always have full access to it! Think of extractions as a way to export data rather than a way to query it and you'll begin to understand how extractions are intended to be used.

Keen is great at collecting and analyzing data, but it's not great at being a database. You will struggle to provide the user experience your users deserve if you attempt to use extractions in a real-time user facing manner. Our recommendation for a use case like yours is to add a database layer that stores your entity data somewhere outside of Keen. Augment that entity data with the results of your queries from Keen and you'll be all set.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Terry's advice is sound, but if you can live with an approximation of pagination than consider making multiple requests with non-overlapping timeframes.

For example, if you wanted to paginate over an hour's worth of data you could issue extractions over 1 minute of data at a time until you reach the desired page size. You would keep track of where you left off to load the next "page", and so forth.

Comment: I actually liked your idea did a quick prototype to split original timeframe into smaller chunks. Here is the ruby [snippet](http://pastie.org/9767984#44)

Comment: Cool! Hmm - the snippet link didn't work for me - can you double check?